# How to Intercept EF operations?

Tags: c#, sql, string, entity-framework, enums

I am currently using Entity Framework for a project and one of my classes have an Enum representing some values.

So far EF is saving the Enums as numbers in the database, but I wanted to save them as their actual string names. For example, the Enum NY is saved as 1, instead of "NY".

I have already seen some ways to make this work, like having a string property with a hidden Enum private field, but I wanted to know if there is a way I can just Intercept EF when it's doing the CRUD operations and then I can change the Enum to a String in the Data Context class.

Comment: I would argue that this is not a problem worth solving. Surrogate keys are superior in both performance and maintainability. Did you know that the State abbreviations changed in the 1960s? Also, what if additional cities get added?

Comment: I think it's a lot readable to have the names on the database than some random numbers that are dependent on a version of my code.

Comment: To address readability in the DB:
1. Views
2. This is why you have the lookup table
As for the code, this is why you use the enum in the first place. And sorry, if you are using EF, you app is already directly linked to your DB.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer You are forgetting about legacy databases which use this pattern. And in many cases it doesn't make sense to have a surrogate key, for example because you have three different states for an entity that can be expressed with a single char in a meaningful way, and you want to use an enum in your to have something even more meaningful. I.e. this obviously applies to small "master" tables, with only a few  rows, or to properties which are not FKs, and don't even have a related table. It's a very good practice to use `Enum` values for this cases

Comment: I currently work on a legacy database that does things this way; it causes a lot of problems!

As for only three values, if a very limited amount of values excuses of from proper DB design, why not hardcode it? It's only three values...

Comment: I am not used to work with databases, so I wanted to be as far as possible from them, this is a program with an internal database (sql server ce) so I am not sure how to configure it to use views since I am using EF code first.

Comment: Well here is a lesson to help you avoid a lot of pain in the future: Always use a meaningless integer as a primary key.

Comment: I have every entity with an int PK, this enum is just an information to be recorded in the data base.

Comment: If it warrants its own table it warrants its own integer primary key. It does not matter whether it is an entity or a lookup.

Plus, you'd be surprised how often lookups become entities.

Comment: You can try your luck with command tree interceptors. But you can also use an unmapped enum property in combination with a mapped text property that converts the enum to and from text.

Comment: @mFeinstein TheCatWhisperer is absolutely correct.  What you are trying to do is a bad database design.  Not to sound mean, but rather to illustrate how serious a design flaw this is - if you were to do this at my shop you wouldn't be working there any longer.

Comment: Why so? Remember I am using EF code first and this makes a lot of things easier but not necessarily gives you the regular DB flexibility... I am a computer engineer, but I am more focused on embedded systems, so I hardly have to deal with DB

Comment: @SamAxe, could you elaborate more why this is wrong? I am kind of a noob on DB and I can't see why this is going  to be so bad.

Comment: @mFeinstein: methodologies and patterns are very important when writing readable and maintainable code.  One should be able to look at how something is done in one place and have a reasonable idea of how a similar task would be accomplished elsewhere.   So while storing the state abbreviations directly in the record is probably not the end of the world - it sets a terrible precedent and it doesn't scale well (next week we're adding international shipping!  yay! oh, wait, the database can't handle that!?  crap.  You're fired.)

Comment: If you want to discuss it further set up a chat room and invite me and anyone else you like.

Comment: Great, will do later when I get home, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that directly: when you map your class with an `Enum` property, that property is mapped to a database `int` column, and you cannot change that in any way. I mean that, as you cannot change the model, there is no way to intercept and convert the `Enum` property value into an string, because the model stubbornly wants an `int`.

That said, there are several ways to make it work:

- having an string property for the key and a `[NotMapped]` `Enum` property that updates that key. *SEE THE NOTE: But the key must be public, and thus accesible through the application code.*
- using a class that have only the enum property and is used in your application domain, and a different class which is used for your EF model, and map the values, for example using `ValueInjecter` or `Automapper`

I usually take the first path and use an attribute that allows me to define the string key for each `Enum` value, so you can reuse this pattern in all the cases in which need to do this.

*NOTE: this part of the answer was wrong: you can map any property regardles of the modifier (`public`, `protected`, `private`, `internal`...). EF conventions only include the `public` properties, and there are no data annotations that can overcome this limitation. But you can use it with the Fluent API. However, as the property is private,you cannot access it directly using the Fluent API. There are several solutions to do it described here: [Code First Data Annotations on non-public properties](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/26/code-first-data-annotations-on-non-public-properties/#more-166)*

If you follow this path, you can have a class like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
  // ...

  [NotMapped]
  public EnumType Value 
  {
    get { /* return KeyForEnum converted to EnumType value */ }
    set { /* set KeyForEnum value from the received EnumType value*/}
  }

  // Use some mechanism to map this private property
  private string KeyForEnum { get; set; } 

  // ...
}
```

As you can see, if you use a class like this, in the app the entity will have a property of `EnumType` type, but in the database it will be an string.

One of the tricks to be able to map it through Fluent API is this:

1) Add an static property that returns an expression able to select the property from an object of this class, i.e.

```
public static readonly Expression<Func<MyEntity,string>> KeyForEnumExpression
   = me => me.KeyForEnum;
```

2) Use it in the fluent API to get the property mapped, like so:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity()
  .Property(MyEntity.KeyForEnumExpression)
```

*LAST NOTE: This will modify the POCO class by adding the static readonly property. You can use Reflection instead to build an expression to access the private property, like you can see here: [EF 4.1 Code First, ¿map private members?](http://geeks.ms/blogs/unai/archive/2011/03/30/ef-4-1-code-first-191-map-private-members.aspx). It's in Spanish, but you can look directly at the code*